# How do I convert from a char array [char; N] to a string slice &str?

Tags: string, char, rust

Given a fixed-length `char` array such as:

```
let s: [char; 5] = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
```

How do I obtain a `&str`?

Comment: Note that `: [char; 5]` is redundant; the type can be inferred.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I put that there to make the question clearer :)

Comment: Why would you ever create an array like this? `"hello"` is 1000% easier and more useful.

Comment: @delnan: sometimes I want to create one with characters that are not known at compile time, e.g. `[c1, c2, c3]`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't without some allocation, which means you will end up with a `String`.

```
let s2: String = s.iter().collect();
```

The problem is that strings in Rust are **not** collections of `char`s, they are UTF-8, which is an encoding without a fixed size per character.

For example, the array in this case would take 5 x 32-bits for a total of 20 bytes. The data of the string would take 5 bytes total (although there's also 3 pointer-sized values, so the overall `String` takes more memory in this case).

---

We start with the array and call [`[]::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter), which yields values of type `&char`. We then use [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) to [convert the `Iterator<Item = &char>` into a `String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-FromIterator%3C%26%27a%20char%3E). This uses the iterator's `size_hint` to [pre-allocate space in the `String`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.25.0/src/liballoc/string.rs#L1646-L1647), reducing the need for extra allocations.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of the `vec!` macro for `String`?

Comment: @Rufflewind I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean `String::from("foo")` or maybe `"foo".to_string()`? In some contexts you can also use `"foo".into()`. You don't really need a macro for anything; those are just function calls. I suppose you could create a method `s` that calls one of them if they are too long...

Comment: I mean something like `str!['h', 'e', 'y']`.

Comment: @Rufflewind Why would you want that instead of just `"hey"`?

Comment: sometimes I want to create one with characters that are not known at compile time, e.g. `[c1, c2, c3]`.

Comment: @Rufflewind perhaps you just want [literator](https://github.com/kmcallister/literator).

Answer (score 6):

Another quick one-liner I didn't see above:

```rust
let whatever_char_array = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
let string_from_char_array = String::from_iter(whatever_char_array);
```

Note:
This feature (iterating over an `array`) was introduced recently. I tried looking for the exact rustc version, but could not...

Comment: > This feature (iterating over an array) was introduced recently. I tried looking for the exact rustc version, but could not...

`std::array::IntoIter` was introduced in 1.51 while the `impl<T, const N: usize> IntoIterator for [T; N]` was introduced in 1.53