# How to create a string from an array of chars?

Tags: arrays, string, char, rust, type-conversion

In the global scope, I have the following definition:

```
static ALPH: [char; 25] = [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O' ];
```

In my `main()`, I'd like to print that entire array, either by element or concatenated into a string, but I have no clue how.

I tried doing the following:

```
let s: String = ALPH.to_string();
```

and then printing the string `s`, but Rust complains about traits not being satisfied.

I tried the usual searching for a solution, but I can only find examples using a `Vec`, not an array like this.

I'm just starting out with Rust, so the strict type adherence is a bit confusing to me, but I'm also not familiar with what libraries I should use.

Comment: Specifically, your case is addressed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23431977/155423): `let s: String = ALPH.iter().cloned().collect();`

Comment: let mut _str = String::from("");
    for x in &ALPH {
        _str.push(*x);
    }
    println!("{}", _str);

Comment: @Davide while that might work, it's not very efficient as it has to allocate more times than needed. Also, **don't prefix that variable name with an underscore**, as that indicates that the variable is deliberately unused. That's not the case here. `let mut s = String::new(); for &x in &ALPH { s.push(x); } println!("{}", s);` is a bit closer to idiomatic (but still not as much as the `collect`).

Comment: @Shepmaster That is a very simple mechanism that shows it works. Nobody said it's the best one but people can understand very easily :-)

Comment: @Davide sure, but you didn't qualify it with any warnings or explanation.  Any newbie who reads that comment might use it without this knowledge and thus introduce sub-par and/or non-idiomatic code, such as by mis-using underscores.

Comment: @Shepmaster If I could answer the question I would be very pleased to explain the code with a nice formatting (including the underscore)

Comment: @Davide feel free to answer [the question this is an exact duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359231/how-do-i-convert-from-a-char-array-char-n-to-a-string-slice-str).

Comment: OK, well, I was confused, because the other question talks about a `vec<A>`, rather than a static, primitive array. Since it is static, do I still need to make a `.cloned()`? Right now, I've tried `ALPH.into_iter().collect()`, seems to work, etc.

Comment: @polemon that's fine, that is actually an enhancement to Rust since that answer was created. I've updated it accordingly.